# Quotient of two Gaussian densities

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) contains formulas for the product of two multivariate Gaussians, but doesn't appear to contain formulas for the quotient of two Gaussians.

$$
\frac{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}_1, \Sigma_1)}{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}_2, \Sigma_2)} = ~??
$$

Note that I'm not looking for the quotient of two random variables ([answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176850/probability-density-function-of-a-quotient-of-two-normal-random-variables)), I just care about the quotient of two PDFs.

**Context:** I'm trying to derive factor analysis from [Roweis and Ghahramani (1999)](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/papers/NC110201.pdf). They apply Bayes rule:

$$
p(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{y}) = \frac{p(\mathbf{y} \mid \mathbf{x}) p(\mathbf{x})}{p(\mathbf{y})} \\
=\frac{\mathcal{N}(C\mathbf{x}, R)\mathcal{N}(0, I)}{\mathcal{N}(0,CC^T + R)} \\
= \frac{\mathcal{N}((R^{-1} + I)^{-1} (R^{-1} C \mathbf{x}), (R^{-1} + I)^{-1})}{\mathcal{N}(0,CC^T + R)} \\
\vdots \\
??? \\
\vdots \\
= \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\beta} \mathbf{y}, I - \boldsymbol{\beta} C), \quad \boldsymbol{\beta} = C^T (C C^T + R)^{-1}
$$

I used the matrix cookbook for the third equality. R is a covariance matrix without any special assumptions at this point in the paper.

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a late answer, but it might still be helpful for people who are googling this problem: In the [PhD thesis of José Miguel Hernández-Lobato](https://repositorio.uam.es/bitstream/handle/10486/6080/37236_hernandez-lobato_jose_miguel.pdf?sequence=1), Appendix C.2 (p. 133) you find the solution to your problem, so you could cite it properly. More easily understandable is this [blog post](http://davmre.github.io/blog/statistics/2015/03/27/gaussian_quotient). It's very similar to the solution for the product of two Gaussian densities. I won't dive into the context you gave, but here's the solution for the quotient of two Gaussian densities:

$$\frac{\mathcal{N}(x|\mathbf{m}_1, \Sigma_1)}{\mathcal{N}(x|\mathbf{m}_2, \Sigma_2)} = \mathcal{N}(x|\mathbf{m}, \Sigma) \cdot \mathcal{Z}$$
where $$\Sigma = (\Sigma_1^{-1}-\Sigma_2^{-1})^{-1}$$
and $$\mathbf{m} = \Sigma(\Sigma_1^{-1}\mathbf{m}_1 - \Sigma_2^{-1}\mathbf{m}_2)$$
furthermore $$\mathcal{Z} = \frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_2-\Sigma_1|}\cdot \frac{1}{\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}_1|\mathbf{m}_2, \Sigma_2-\Sigma_1)}.$$